# Global variable or property in MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I want to be able to set some sort of variable or flag in the map phase of my MR job that I can check **after** the job has completed. I think the best way to demonstrate what I want with some code: p.s I am using Hadoop 2.2.0

```
public class MRJob {

  public static class MapperTest 
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{


    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Do some computation to get new value and key
        ...
        //Check if new value equal to some condition e.g if(value < 1) set global variable to true

        context.write(newKey, newValue);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "word_count");
   //set job configs

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    //Here I want to be able to check if my global variable has been set to true by any one of the mappers

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Counter` for that matter.

```
public static enum UpdateCounter {
  UPDATED
}

 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if(value < 1) {
      context.getCounter(UpdateCounter.UPDATED).increment(1);
    }

    context.write(newKey, newValue);
}
```

After the job you can check:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "word_count");
//set job configs

job.waitForCompletion(true);
long counter = job.getCounters().findCounter(UpdateCounter.UPDATED).getValue();   

if(counter > 0) 
  // some mapper has seen the condition
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify do I create the UpdateCounter inside the mapper class?

Comment: @Mo. it doesn't matter where, as long as the class is accessible at runtime.

Comment: Sorry one last question. I have a slightly similar use case where I need to set a custom global value value.
e.g. in the mapper something like:
``map(key, ....){
   if(key=="foo"){
      globalVariable=value;
   }
}``
I then would need to access that variable after the job is finished similar to the counter.

Thanks

Comment: @Mo. write a file to HDFS then, there is no built-in facily to easily make this possible.